# Amazon Web services - retrieving a wishlist

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipe, amazon-product-api

I've been tinkering with Yahoo Pipes and the [Amazon Product Advertising API (formerly ECS) SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/) to retrieve my wishlist.

The problem is that although I can get all the items on my wishlist just fine, it seems to include items that I've deleted too.

Has anyone else used this API and noticed this? Is there a way around it?

UPDATE:

Requested additional information in comments...

Here is the URL I use to fetch the wishlist XML:

```
http://webservices.amazon.co.uk/onca/xml?SubscriptionId=[my subs id]&Service=AWSECommerceService&ResponseGroup=ListItems&ProductPage=1&ProductGroup=Book&Operation=ListLookup&ListType=WishList&ListId=[my list id]
```

And here is the relevant part of the XML response:

```
<ListId>[my list id]</ListId>
<ListName>Wishlist</ListName>
<TotalItems>132</TotalItems>
<TotalPages>14</TotalPages>
<ListItem>
    <ListItemId>EPIE5559HKT391</ListItemId>
    <DateAdded>2003-11-17</DateAdded>
    <QuantityDesired>1</QuantityDesired>
    <QuantityReceived>0</QuantityReceived>
    <Item>
        <ASIN>5557205521</ASIN>
        <ItemAttributes>
            <Title>Horton hears a who</Title>
        </ItemAttributes>
    </Item>
</ListItem>
...
```

The rest of the XML is just either more list items like that, or information about the request at the top of the response.

Comment: Can you post up an example of the XML you get back from the request? It's hard to say how to filter it without seeing what it looks like.

Comment: Close me please!
(See my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. This is pilot error.

I would explain what I'd done wrong, but I'm too embarassed.

Deleted items do not show up in wish-lists after all. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything to indicate whether the item has been deleted from the list in either the XML or in the documented parameters to send with the request. At this point, I guess your best bet is to start stalking the [forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=9) and ask there if stalking reveals nothing. Sorry, both for the lateness of this response and the fact that it's not overly helpful.